# Enviar parámetro extra a modal Bootstrap en typeahead

Tags: php, bootstrap, modal

Necesito pasar un parámetro extra en el código jQuery para el archivo que hace el *GET* y no lo logro hacer.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddProjecto" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Agregar</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="AddProjecto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Alta de nuevo proyecto</h5>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                  </button>
      </div>
      <div class="dash">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $.get("Process/SearchProyecto.php", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("#proyecto").typeahead({
      source: data
    });
  }, 'json');
</script>
```

Estoy necesitando pasar un parámetro extra en la función de jQuery para poder hacer un *GET* en el archivo **SearchProceso.php**